# Why does list.append evaluate to false in a boolean context?

Tags: python, list

Is there a reason being `list.append` evaluating to false? Or is it just the C convention of returning 0 when successful that comes into play?

```
>>> u = []
>>> not u.append(6)
True
```

Comment: A possibly better way to phrase:  *why does python not use the `Builder` pattern .. so we can do `u.append(6).append(7). ..`*  This is annoying.

Comment: @javadba Why not just do `u.extend((6, 7))`?

Comment: @Stefan  `append()` and `extend()` have different effects and are not interchangeable

Comment: @javadba What difference? My extend has the same effect as your two appends.

Comment: extend() retains a single list if the elements were a list whereas append() will be a list of lists. In the above case they are not so it's a special case that does end up the same between extend() and append().

Comment: @javadba Not sure what you mean, but it sounds wrong. It doesn't matter that we used numbers. If we use lists instead, my extend still has the same effect as your two appends.

Comment: @StefanPochmann  difference between append() and extend()  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252703/what-is-the-difference-between-pythons-list-methods-append-and-extend

Comment: @javadba Not sure what that shall tell me. I know the difference. But you seem mistaken about `extend`.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Most Python methods that mutate a container in-place return `None` -- an application of the principle of [Command-query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command-query_separation).  (Python's always reasonably pragmatic about things, so a few mutators do return a usable value when getting it otherwise would be expensive or a mess -- the `pop` method is a good example of this pragmatism -- but those are definitely the exception, not the rule, and there's no reason to make `append` an exception).

Answer (score 20):

`None` evaluates to `False` and in python a function that does not return anything is assumed to have returned `None`.

If you type:

```
>> print u.append(6)
None
```

Tadaaam :)

Comment: Mutators (like append, extend, sort, etc.) which update a list do not return a value.

Comment: `None` doesn't *evaluate* to `False`.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake Try `bool(None)`

Comment: @Chris_Rands `None` is not a boolean, which is why you need the `bool` function to convert it (done implicitly by `not`). Yes, I know it's a quibble but it's `True`.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake  No-one said `None` is a boolean, but it does evaluate to `False`

Comment: @Chris_Rands I guess my quibble is with the phrase *evaluates to*, which admittedly is due to the OP. As I said I don't dispute the gist of the answer (who would) and I know that `None` is 'falsy'.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake: I am open to suggestions, *evaluates* remains the best expression I have so far.

Comment: @SwiftsNamesake I find *evaluates* clearer than Python's own semantics, `help(bool)` says "bool(x): Returns True when the argument x is true". But `x` is true seems too similar to `x is True`, which of course has a completely different meaning

Answer (score 7):

because `.append` method returns `None`, therefore `not None` evaluates to `True`. Python on error usually raises an error:

```
>>> a = ()
>>> a.append(5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    a.append(5)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Answer (score 5):

It modifies the list in-place, and returns `None`.  `None` evaluates to false.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it returns `None`

```
>>> print u.append(6)
None
>>> print not None
True
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Method `append` modifies the list in-place and the return value `None`

In your case, you are creating an array — [6] — on the fly, then discarding it. The variable b ends up with the return value of None.

Why?
This comply with the principle of [Command–query separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) devised by Bertrand Meyer.
It states that every method should either be a command that performs an action, or a query that returns data to the caller, but not both.
In your example:

```
u.append(6)
```

`append` modified the state of `[]`,  so it’s not a best practice to return a value compliance with the principle.

In theoretical terms, this establishes a measure of sanity, whereby one can reason about a program's state without simultaneously modifying that state.

CQS is well-suited to the object-oriented methodology such as python.

Comment: This also destroys the `builder()` pattern.  It is one of the many reasons python is difficult to use.

Answer (score 0):

The `list.append` function returns `None`. It just adds the value to the list you are calling the method from.

Here is something that'll make things clearer:

```
>>> u = []
>>> not u
False
>>> print(u.append(6)) # u.append(6) == None
None    
>>> not u.append(6) # not None == True
True
```