# Python Append vs list+list

Tags: python, append

I read [Python list + list vs. list.append()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589549/python-list-list-vs-list-append), which is a similar question, but my question is more in relation to the code below

```
a = [[]] * 4
b = [[]] * 4
a[3] = a[3] + [1]
b[3].append(1)
print a, b
```

Which gives:

```
[[],[],[],[1]] [[1],[1],[1],[1]]
```

Why would these 2 be any different?  I've never run into an example like this where these 2 methods have different outputs...

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36322067/the-meaning-of-on-list-in-python/36322093#36322093 There can be a major difference between creating vs modifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a[3] = a[3] + [1]` is not modifying `a[3]`.  Instead, it is putting a new item there.  `a[3] + [1]` creates a list that is just like `a[3]` except that it has an extra one at the end.  Then, `a[3] = ...` sets `a` at the index `3` to that new list.

`b[3].append(1)` accesses `b[3]` and uses its `.append()` method.  The `.append()` method works on the list itself and puts a one at the end of the list.  Since `[[]] * 4` creates a list with four copies of another list, the `.append()` method reveals its changes in all items of `b`.