# Difference between dict[item].append(word) and dict[item] + [word]

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax

The structure of my dictionary is:

```
 key             val
 item         a list of values
```

How I initiated my `dict`:

```
dict[item] = [word]
type(dict[item]) ---> gives me list
```

When going down the loop and try to add more values to the list with the same key, `dict[item].append(word)` gives me `None` whereas `dict[item] + [word]` works

Why is this the case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list + list vs. list.append()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589549/python-list-list-vs-list-append)

Comment: By the way `dict[item] + [word]` won't update the actual list inside the dictionary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The code `dict[item].append(word)` mutates the list at `dict[item]`, and the return value of the function `append` is `None`.
- The code `dict[item] + [word]` does not mutate the list at `dict[item]`, and just computes a concatenation of two lists.

This is equivalent to:

```
arr = [1]
res = arr + [2]
assert res == [1, 2]
assert arr == [1]
res = arr.append(2)
assert res is None
assert arr == [1, 2]
```

For the example from the question to work, the equivalent code to `append` is:

```
dict[item] += [word]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using .append()**

```
d = {'example': ['string']}
d['example'].append('test') # mutates the list
print d
>> {'example': ['string','test']}
```

**Using *list* + *list***

```
d = {'example': ['string']}
d['example'] + ['test'] # return {'example':['string', 'test]} but no mutation
print d
>> {'example': ['string']}
```