# heapify returns NoneType

Tags: python

I have

```
b = heapify([5,4,9,1])
```

and if I do a

```
type(b)
```

It says it's NoneType instead of list type,  anyone know what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: It's generally considered bad style to use `l` as a variable name because it can so easily be mistaken for `1` or `I` depending on the font.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `heapify()` method transforms the list in-place.  This means that it alters the list, but does not returned the modified list. As agf mentions below, `heapify()` returns `None` to protect you from this mistake. Therefore, if you do

```
lst = [5,4,9,1]
heapify(lst)
type(lst)
```

you will see that `lst` is now heapified. See the [library reference](http://docs.python.org/library/heapq.html#heapq.heapify) for more info.

Comment: It's worth adding that all (or nearly all) of the Python methods that act in place return `None`, so you don't accidentally use an in-place method when you didn't mean to.

Comment: Alex Martelli himself explains it well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682567/why-does-pythons-list-append-evaluate-to-false

Comment: You will get a `None` from every function that doesn't explicitly `return` a value. `def f(): pass` for instance.

Answer (score 1):

`heapify` mutates the list passed to it; just like how `l.sort()` does.

```
>>> import heapq
>>> l = [9, 8, 7, 6]
>>> heapq.heapify(l)
>>> l
[6, 8, 7, 9]
```