# Use multiple functions at once on a list

Tags: python

Basically, I have a list and I want to perform multiple functions on it at once. For example,

```
List = [1,2,3,4,5]
List.extend([1,2,3,4,5]).sort().reverse()
```

I would like the result to be `[5,5,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1]`.

I haven't used Python in a while, but I know I've done something like this before. Is it something simple I'm missing or what?

It has to all be on one line by the way.

Comment: Why does it have to be all on one line?

Comment: Trust me, if the requirements weren't that it had to be all on one line this would be much easier. But I guess it's about learning to condense code.

Comment: If you are learning Python, you should learn that sometimes you need uncondense code to emphasize readability over terseness.

Comment: if you want to really piss some people off, use semicolons, and chain the commands lol

Comment: I agree that learning to condense the code before actually knowing how it works is kind of pointless. But it's a tradeoff; getting higher grades or actually learning the material. I know that learning the material is more important in the long run, but grades are also important. Today's educational system I guess :/

Comment: @BrenBarn, obviously it's faster if is all on one line :p

Comment: Oh, this is a homework problem.  Geez.

Comment: @BrenBarn, I'm not asking you to do it, I just thought there was a way to use multiple functions on one line. Thanks for the input though..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most Python methods that mutate a container in-place [return None](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1682601/174728)

However your example can easily be handled in one line

```
L = [1,2,3,4,5]
L = sorted(L+[1,2,3,4,5], reverse=True)
```

Keeping in the spirit of the challenge, it's not hard to chain the operations (because they always return `None`)

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> L.extend([1,2,3,4,5]) or L.sort() or L.reverse() or L
[5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Here's another way

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> (L.extend([1,2,3,4,5]), L.sort(), L.reverse()) and L
[5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

And you can let your imagination run wild

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> max(L.extend([1,2,3,4,5]), L.sort(), L.reverse(), L) # Python2.x only
[5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Comment: These are pretty *ugly* tricks producing unreadable code for non-Python gurus and therefore deserves a downvote...no trickery please

Comment: I actually like this answer, but I'm quite new to Python. Are the commas ugly tricks too? I think they're pretty useful.

Comment: I agree with @esaelPsnoroMoN: Do as you want at home, but don't advertise it. -1.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot chain the above operations since they are performed in-place.
As alternatives, use `sorted()` and `reversed()`.

Comment: And why exactly in-place operations prevent chaining? If `sort` and `reverse` had returned reference to the original list, the example in the OP would be possible.

Comment: Why do you want to argue? As said: the methods are *in-place* and there result is None. So it is obviously that you can not chain *POINT*

Comment: @esaelPsnoroMoN Because it's precision that matters. The lack of return value prevents chaining, not in-place operation.

Comment: @rkhayrov, The are detailed reasons for the decision on the Python dev list some time last century

Comment: @esaelPsnoroMoN I find your comments not constructive, and borderline offensive. If you haven't noticed, I am not an OP. I haven't suggested that Python does this wrong. I've only pointed out that your answer contains logical fallacy.

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5]*2
>>> l.sort(reverse=True)
>>> l
[5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Or even shorter:

```
>>> sorted([1,2,3,4,5]*2,reverse=True)
[5, 5, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Each of those functions acts on the list in-place, returning `None` and not the modified list. You'd have to do something like

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
l = reversed(sorted(l + [1,2,3,4,5]))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not perfect but interesting..

```
class chain():
    def __init__(self, my_object):
        self.o = my_object

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        x = getattr(self.o, attr)
        if hasattr(x, '__call__'):
            method = x
            return lambda *args: self if method(*args) is None else method(*args)
        else:
            prop = x
            return prop

list_ = chain([1, 2, 3, 0])
print list_.extend([9,5]).sort().reverse()
```

Answer (score 0):

The functions `extend`, `sort` and `reverse` doesn't return list but change the list on which they are called. Chaining relies on a fact that previous function returns some value and works on it.

E.g. `s="abc"` then you can do `s.upper().lower()` as `.upper()` return a new string in uppercase (ans same for `.lower()`).