# Does a Python list need to be defined in order to append something to it?

Tags: python, list, append

I need to know why the following two blocks of code return different outputs. I have:

```
somelist = ['foo', 'bar']
somelist.append('baz')
print somelist
```

prints `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` as expected. However,

```
print ['foo', 'bar'].append('baz')
```

prints `None`. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Thanks all. Is there a way to use the `append` function and `print` command in one line of code?

Comment: Well.... `.append` returns `None` and `print ['foo', 'bar'].append('baz')` prints whatever `.append` returns.

Comment: Or this one:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682567/why-does-pythons-list-append-evaluate-to-false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.append` on a list **mutates** the list.  Since it is mutating the list, python takes the convention that the function should return `None` to make it explicitly clear that the function's purpose is to change it's arguments (in this case, the list instance bound that the method is bound to).

Answer (score 2):

`list.append` is an in-place operation, meaning that it returns `None`, but it alters the actual list itself.