# list append gives None as result

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, append

i just wrote a function that should print out all the values 2 dictionaries have in common.
so if use the following line in my function:

```
print list_intersection([1, 3, 5], [5, 3, 1])
```

The output should be:

```
[1, 3, 5]
```

I wrote the following code to solve this problem:

```
def list_intersection(list_1, list_2):
    empty_list = []
    for number in list_1:
        if number in list_2:
            return empty_list.append(number)
```

The problem is that i only get None as output, but if i use the following code:

```
def list_intersection(list_1, list_2):
    empty_list = []
    for number in list_1:
        if number in list_2:
           return number
```

I get the numbers printed out one by one that are in both lists. I have no idea why my program isn't just putting the numbers both lists have in common into my empty_list and return me my empty_list

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the assertion could be made that this isn't exactly a duplicate. For the reason why `.append()` returns `None` please see Alex Martelli's erudite [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1682601/42346).

For your code instead do:

```
def list_intersection(list_1, list_2):
    intersection = []
    for number in list_1:
        if number in list_2:
            intersection.append(number)
    return intersection
```

This avoids the following pitfalls:

1. Returning `None` instead of the list intersection.
2. Returning `None` for *each* element of `list_2`.