# [] became None after appending

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, append

I am fairly new to python. 
I was trying to store raw input to an empty list. And apparently, the input didn't go into the empty list. Then what went wrong?

```py
Latitude = []
Longitude = []
print Latitude #**THIS GIVES []**

Lat_input = raw_input("What is your latitude:")
Latitude = Latitude.append(Lat_input)
print Latitude # **HERE I GOT NONE**

Long_input = raw_input("WHat is your longitude:")
Longitude = Longitude.append(Long_input)
```

I looked up some other postings, still didn't figure out what I did wrong.
What did I miss? Why is my list gone?
Thanks, guys!

Comment: possible duplicate of [list append gives None as result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26151795/list-append-gives-none-as-result)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`append` is an in-place operation; it doesn't return a value.

Just run:

```
Longitude.append(Long_input)
```

...not

```
Longitude = Longitude.append(Long_input)
```

---

This is by design and intent: Returning `None` rather than a value makes it clear that a function is being called for its side effects rather than its return value.

If you didn't want to modify the existing `Longitude` in place, but instead wanted to create a new list with the new item appended, then you might instead use:

```
Longitude = Longitude + [Long_input]
```