# Why do mutating methods for Python's built-in collection types return nothing instead of the collection itself?

Tags: python

Being able to use chaining for collection operations and being able to embed collection-modifying expressions inside other statements that will then use the modified collection can be really handy and concise, and I find myself regularly annoyed by the fact that I need separate statement lines every time I want to modify a collection in python and then immediately use the collection again.

Examples are: `list.append`, `list.extend`, `dict.update`

Is there a specific reason (philosophical or otherwise) why mutating methods on python's built-in methods return nothing (None) instead of the collection itself?  I realize I can extend the built-ins to add chainability, but I wonder why the original designs didn't support this.

Comment: Built-in types? Can you provide some specific examples which wind you up?

Comment: from a "philisophical" point of view, returning `None` makes it abundantly clear that the collection was mutated.  This has the tendency to disambiguate methods that mutate the object (`self`) and methods that only use the data that `self` holds to create something else.  There are a few notable exceptions when getting a hold of information that you might have wanted would be exceedingly cumbersome otherwise (`list.pop` comes to mind immediately).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1682567/748858 is the earliest question that I can find that addresses this.  That answer links [this article on command-query separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation).

Comment: One of the clearest justifications for returning `None` is in [this python-dev post from GVR](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/038855.html).

Comment: The article mgilson linked to on command-query separation and ekhumoro's link to Guido's post to the python-dev list are very enlightening.  I assumed there was a great justification for this decision, and knowing the justification makes me feel good about it when I can't go all jQuery on my python. :)

Comment: Very similar question: [Why do these list methods (append, sort, extend, remove, clear, reverse) return None rather than the resulting list?](/q/11205254/4518341) (I would close it as a duplicate, but the scope of that question is more narrow, even if the answers are effectively the same.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid confusion over whether the return value is a copy or not.

To my knowledge, no Python built-in modifies its argument in place and returns the argument itself (stuff like `dict.pop` and `dict.setdefault` do return something, but it's not the `dict` that was mutated), so *if* you receive a non-`None` return, you know it's a new object, not the object you called it on. Similarly, if you receive a `None` return for something that clearly mutates, it must have mutated the argument. This is closely related to the concept of [command–query separation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation); you either *do* something or *return* something new, you don't do both at once.

Conventions from other languages can be more confusing; if you see `listb = lista.sort()` you hope that `.sort()` returns a new `list`, because otherwise, `listb` is just an alias of `lista`, and the separate names do nothing but invite confusion. But it might not (after all, sorting to a new `list` is typically more expensive than in-place sorts, so outside of a purely functional language, you'd want default sorts to occur in place), and you're stuck repeatedly checking the documentation to verify.

Python's approach is pretty simple:

1. Mutable types have methods that mutate in place and return nothing (`None`)
2. Immutable types have methods that produce and return modified copies of the original value

Most third-party packages follow this approach, making it easier to learn them as a side-effect; if they follow Python's conventions, then their behavior is predictable.

The other reason Python preferred this approach is [because Guido van Rossum believes it encourages more readable code](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2003-October/038855.html); `val = mylist.append(foo).extend(bar).sort().reverse().pop()` is needlessly hard to read, and languages that allow it, however much they discourage, tend to get a lot of code written that uses that approach. Python's general approach is to encourage one, and only one, obvious way to do something, and to have that approach be readable/maintainable.