# Python - Traverse list of dictionaries - Error as NoneType

Tags: list, python-2.7, nonetype

Why do i get 'None' as output while executing below code

```
listdic = [{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}]
listA = []
for i in listdic:
    listB = listA.append(i)

print listB
```

I get the below output: None

**Expected result:**
[{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3},{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}]

Comment: possible duplicate of [why does python's list.append evaluate to false?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682567/why-does-pythons-list-append-evaluate-to-false)

Comment: the `append` method doesn't return anything..

Comment: yeah I got it.. Thanks matsjoyce and Ankit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append()` changes the list. It returns None.

```
l = [1, 2]

print(l.append(3))

print(l)
```