# Why does append modify the original list? [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok, so here's the python code:

```
example = [1,2,3]
a = example
b = example.append(4)

print(a)
print(b)
```

And the output is:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
None
```

while I was expecting something like:

```
[1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4]
```

why does "a" gets modified even when i was only modifying "example"

and why does "b" return "None"

Comment: You didn't make a copy, you created an additional reference.

Comment: In-place operations always return `None`. The original list is altered, no need to return another reference. See [why does python's list.append evaluate to false?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1682567)

Comment: `b` is None because the return value of `append` is None. That's a common idiom for functions that modify an object.

Comment: is there a way how i can COPY the list into another variable 
e.g in this case i would like to make a copy of "example" into "a"