# What don't I understand about the order of execution and/or operations in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, execution

I have a list and I am trying to obtain either a set or a list of the unique items in that list. I also need to remove all instances of a specific item from the list, which in this case is `'USD'`.

```
currencies = ['AUD', 'AUD', 'CAD', 'CHF', 'EUR', 'GBp', 'GBp', 'HKD', 'JPY', 'KRW', 'NOK', 'SEK', 'TWD', 'USD', 'USD', 'ZAr']
```

I initially tried,

```
foreign_currencies = set(currencies).discard('USD')
```

but noticed that the function was returning `None`.

In order to get it to work, I had to do it in two steps.

```
foreign_currencies = set(currencies)
foreign_currencies = foreign_currencies.discard('USD')
```

However, I don't see why this would resolve the issue.  Can anyone tell me why this is the case and/or explain what I am not understanding about the order of execution?  If `.discard` modifies the set in-place and returns `None`, I would expect the results of the second example to be the same as the first.  In the first example, is `.discard()` being called before the set is constructed? Is it something deeper that I am not getting?

EDIT: Although the responses in "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682567/why-does-pythons-list-append-evaluate-to-false" answer my question, my question was not a duplicate. The question posed was not the same, the answer is.

Comment: `discard` modifies the set in place and returns `None`.

Comment: Your second code should have the same result as your first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `discard` does not return any output.It does an in place removal.

You need to do

```
foreign_currencies = set(currencies)
foreign_currencies.discard('USD') #do not assign this as `discard does not return anything.
print foreign_currencies #now you have the currect result
```

Answer (score 0):

As vks said, discard is an in place operation. This is what your code 'wants' to do:

```
foreign_currencies = set(currencies)
foreign_currencies.discard('USD')
```