# Why is a loop over a list infinite when I use insert()

Tags: python, list, for-loop, insert, text-files

When I run the function `appendA` by entering a value for `crop` that is already contained within  the .txt file, `index`  and `newlines` are printed ad infinitum with `index` as a sequence of ever-ascending numbers starting with 1, which alternates with `newlines` being printed as 'None'. Does anyone know why this might be?

By the way the idea with `newlines` is that it is a modified form of the list `lines`, with `split_2` being inserted at the same position (`index`) as `line` , replacing it.

```
crop = input("Which crop? ")
quantity = input("How many? ")
newlines = []
newlines = list(newlines)

def appendA ():

 file_initial = open('cropdatabase.txt', 'r')
 lines = file_initial.readlines()

 for line in lines:
    if crop in line:
        index = lines.index(line)
        print (index)
        line = str(line)
        split_2 = line.split (' ')
        split_2.append (quantity + '  ')
        split_2 = str(split_2)

        # everything works up to here.

        newlines = lines.insert (index, split_2)
        print (newlines)

file.close()

def appendB ():

 file = open('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+')
 file.write ('\n')
 file.write (crop + ' ')
 file.write (quantity + ' ')


with open('cropdatabase.txt', 'a+') as file:
 if crop in open('cropdatabase.txt').read():
    appendA ()
 else:
    appendB ()
file.close ()
```

Comment: You keep adding stuff to the same iterable you're iterating over. How would you expect that process to end then?

Comment: But surely it should only affect the line in which `crop` is in?

Comment: What am I adding to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your misunderstanding probably originates from how `insert()` and iteration work.

Say you have a list with 3 items. When you do `for item in my_list`, Python will not look for how many items there are and iterate over that many indices. It will keep iterating until the list has been exhausted. When you insert an item in an index, it will push every other item in the list one index forward. So, what is at index `i` in the current loop, it'll be at `i+1` for the next one and you'll run into it again. Here's a simple demonstration.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> for index, item in enumerate(a):
...     print(item)
...     a.insert(index, '{0}{0}'.format(index))
...     print(a)

0
['00', 0, 1, 2]
0
['00', '11', 0, 1, 2]
0
['00', '11', '22', 0, 1, 2]
0
['00', '11', '22', '33', 0, 1, 2]
0
['00', '11', '22', '33', '44', 0, 1, 2]
0
['00', '11', '22', '33', '44', '55', 0, 1, 2]
...
```

Did you mean to modify the list at index `i` instead of inserting a new element? For example, `lines[index] = split_2`.

The other thing about `insert()` is that [it modifies the list in-place and returns None as its value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682567/why-does-pythons-list-append-evaluate-to-false), which is what `newlines` refers to and why it's printing `None`. Other examples of such functions are `list.append()`, `list.sort()` and `random.shuffle()`.