# NoneType returned by y.extend(z)?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to figure out the behavior below. Specifically, what is assigned to y / why that is assigned, in the below example when I set `y = y.extend(z)`. I can see that it's a NoneType object, I'm just not fully getting *why*. Eg. **what are the potential use(s) [if any] of this functionality...** I see that y.extend(z) is an in-place mutation operation -- that being the case, my current thinking is that I would expect an error when I attempt to assign it to a variable, not a return of `NoneType`. Why am I wrong / why is Python built this way / how is having a `None` return useful?

```
>>> x = []
>>> y = []
>>> z = [1, 2]
>>> x.extend(z)
>>> x
[1, 2]
>>> y = y.extend(z)
>>> y
>>> y.extend(z)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'extend'
```

To give you some context, I was attempting to do something like this:

```
l = l[:x].extend(y)
```

which I now know I should do as follows:

```
l = l[:x] + y # where y is already a list
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does append return none in this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641119/why-does-append-return-none-in-this-code) or [Why does “return list.sort()” return None, not the list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7301110/why-does-return-list-sort-return-none-not-the-list)

Comment: Why would you expect an error? It is perfectly valid to assign None to a variable.

Comment: Many methods of [mutable sequence types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types), like `list`, modify the object in-place and don't return a value (which is the same as returning `None`) — the `extend()` and `append()` methods are two of them.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't a "duplicate" of a question relating to .append because (1) I am asking about .extend and duplicate means "one or more IDENTICAL things", and (2) I am asking WHY it returns None

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner: that question is answered in several places; both on the duplicates here directly and on posts linked from there. See [Why does Python's list.append evaluate to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1682567) for example.

Comment: @MartijnPieters so... is `.append` identical to `.extend`? Because if not, it can't be a duplicate. In fact, I searched for info on this under `.extend` and I didn't find anything. You're analogizing `.append` and `.extend`, which I get, but that doesn't make them identical for people searching for answers.

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner: the *same principle applies*. And to `list.sort()`, `list.reverse()`, `list.insert()` and `list.remove()`.

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner: and there is a reason we don't delete duplicates, they act as sign-posts to the canonical post. Although in this case there are a few more places to clean this up.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I get that -- but a user having trouble with `.extend` (like me) isn't going to be able to search the site for the principle, are they? It also straight up isn't a duplicate under the dictionary meaning.

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner: the point of duplicates is to lead to canonical answers. The question doesn't have to be a strict duplicate, the answer is still the same: because the object is mutated in-place.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well, I have learned something about the way SO works, so thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I see that y.extend(z) is an in-place mutation operation -- that being
>   the case, I'd expect an error when I attempt to assign it to a
>   variable, not a return of NoneType, n'est pas?

Well, why? `extend` does not return anything, and in terms of Python it returns `None`. You are assigning `None` to a variable and this is pretty well in Python. Then you're trying to call something from the `None` and this is, obviously, invalid.

Comment: I get that -- but what's the point in returning None? If I wanted to assign None to a variable, I'd just assign it, I wouldn't assign the result of a function.

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner: because `list.extend()` modifies the list **in place**. It doesn't create a new list. The convention in Python is to then return `None` becauses you already have a reference to the object.  The same applies to `dict.update()`, `set.add()`, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's good to know -- so I suppose my question is why is that the convention, or is there a reason?

Comment: @NotAnAmbiTurner: See my comments on the question.

Answer (score 1):

`.extend` doesn't return the modified array; it simply performs the extension in place. That means `y` will be modified, but the function doesn't return anything.

```
>>> y = []
>>> y.extend([1, 2])
>>> y
[1, 2]
```

Comment: `extend` returns None. Functions always return a value

Comment: [None is frequently used to represent the absence of a value](https://docs.python.org/2/library/constants.html#None) tho. extend doesn't return anything, so the result of running the function is None :P

Comment: Eh it's pretty much the same thing tho

Comment: It's incorrect to say that functions don't return anything. None is a value, no matter what

Comment: Alright I'll edit my answer then.

Answer (score 0):

The extend methods of lists directly modifies the list instead of returning a new list.

You should just do

```
y.extend(z)
```