# Assign value of a list into another list while using append or insert method returning None as output

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am a beginner in python. I am trying to assign value of a list into another list while using append or insert method. However, the output is always none. Can you please advise. Below is the piece of code:

**Input:**

```
guest_list = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD']
new_guest_list = guest_list.append("XX")
print(new_guest_list)
```

**Output:**

```
None
```

**Input:**

```
guest_list = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD']
new_guest_list = guest_list.insert(0,"XX")
print(new_guest_list)
```

**Output:**

```
None
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does list.append evaluate to false?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682567/why-does-list-append-evaluate-to-false)

Comment: Append doesn't return anything ... Therefore new_guest _list never initialized /defined

Comment: For what you're trying to do (make a new `list` without modifying the old one, I assume), you'd want `new_guest_list = guest_list + ["XX"]` or `new_guest_list = `["XX"] + guest_list`, both of which keep `guest_list` unchanged and make a new `list` for `new_guest_list`. `list.append` always modifies `guest_list` in place, and never makes a copy of it (which keeps the performance acceptable; making a fresh copy for every append would make appending to large `list`s intolerably expensive).

Answer (score 1):

```
 guest_list = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD'] 
 guest_list.append("XX") 
 print(guest_list)

 guest_list = ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD'] 
 guest_list.insert(0,"XX") 
 print(guest_list)
```

What you can do is first append the data to the list and then print the list itself as append does not return anything hence you are getting `None` as an output.If you want to assign this list to another variable then you can do this after appending data.

```
new_list=guest_list
print(new_list)
```

Comment: To be clear though, `new_list=guest_list` isn't making any new `list`s at all. It's just aliasing the same `list` to a new name (in C terms, both `guest_list` and `new_list` would be pointers to the same memory address); if you change it through either name, they'll both appear to be modified (because they're both aliases to the same `list`). If you want to shallow copy the `list`, use `new_list = guest_list[:]` or `new_list = list(guest_list)` or (on Py3 only) `new_list = guest_list.copy()`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yep, I know that.This was in case if he wants to address the new list with a different variable, although a change in one list would affect the other. list.copy() or list.deepcopy() would be useful here.

Comment: Well, not `list.deepcopy`, since that doesn't exist. :-) You need `copy.deepcopy(guest_list)` for a true deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `append()` works.  The function adds the item to `guest_list` but returns nothing (`None`) so when you're setting `new_guest_list = guest_list.append('XX')` the interpreter is essentially doing the following:

1.) Add the item 'XX' to `guest_list`
2.) Set `new_guest_list` to `None`

If your `guest_list` is mutable (i.e you want it to be updated), just `guest_list.append('XX')` will suffice and it'll be updated.
If however you want your `guest_list` immutable (i.e. keep it unchanged for the record), you will want to:

1.) Optional: Set your `guest_list` as a `tuple` object (note the use of regular bracket instead of square bracket), this way it will prevent accidental changes as `tuple` objects are immutable:

```
guest_list = ('AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD')
```

2.) Set your new list as a copy of your `guest_list`:

```
new_guest_list = list(guest_list)
```

3.) Append your new item to new list:

```
new_guest_list.append('XX')
```

The values of your `guest_list` and `new_guest_list` will be as follow:

```
guest_list: ('AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD')
new_guest_list: ['AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD', 'XX']
```