# Unable to append directly to a list

Tags: python-3.x

Easy question here.

In Python 3 -why is this meaningful?:

```
  x=[1,2,3]
  y=[4,5,6]
  tst=x.append(y)
```

But this gives you nothing - even though it is the same thing

```
tst=[1,2,3].append([4,5,6])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign value of a list into another list while using append or insert method returning None as output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48175707/assign-value-of-a-list-into-another-list-while-using-append-or-insert-method-ret)

Comment: In both cases `tst` will have `None`. The difference is that in the first one you actually append to another object while in the second you append to a list literal which doesn't affect anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tst` points to the result of the `append` method on the object `[1, 2, 3]` which is `None` since `append` returns nothing, it just mutates the object.

```
>>> type(tst)
<class 'NoneType'>
```

If you, however, create a variable that points to the mutable object `[1, 2, 3]`:

```
tst = [1,2,3]
tst.append([4,5,6])
```

You get the desired result:

```
>>> tst
[1, 2, 3, [4, 5, 6]]
```

In other words, `append` does not return back a list but mutates the object.

Answer (score 1):

Return value of `x.append(...)` is None so it's waste of time to save it in `tst` variable !
To add all of y items to the end of x you can do something as below :

```
tst = x + y
```