# I am trying to make a list of 3D points by combining 3 lists in Python

Tags: python

When you run the script below in Python, you get the results shown.

1) I don't understand why it's able to print c just fine, but when I say z = shuffle(c) z returns zero. Shouldn't it just give me a mixed up c?

```
import random 
a = list(range(1,99))   
b = list(range(1,99))   
c =list(range(1,99))   
print(c)   
x=random.shuffle(a)     
y=random.shuffle(b)  
z=random.shuffle(c)   
print(x)   
q=(x,y,z)   
print(q)    

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19,
20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36,
37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53,
54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70,
71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87,
88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98]   
None   
(None, None, None)
```

2) Ideally, I want make lots of q points each of which is given an x, y and z so q1=(x1,y1,z1) and q2=(x2,y2,z2) etc. So I thought I could iterate over it, but I'm not sure how to write it in less mathematical terms and more of a python way.
I tried

```
for i in range(len(x,y,z)):   
    q=(x[i],y[i],z[i])
```

But I don't think that's how Python works.

Comment: Please fix your code format

Comment: Do you want all `99 * 99 * 99` permutations of these?  If so, try `itertools`

Comment: not every possible combination, just 99 q's

Comment: `random.shuffle` operates in place and returns `None`. There are a billion dupes about this (also for `list.sort`), hopefully somebody will find one.

Comment: Just use `zip(a, b, c)` after calling `random.shuffle`, and don't bother assigning the result of `random.shuffle` to a variable, as it is an in-place operation.

Comment: @wim I can't find a good match for the question, but here's a reasonably generic answer from Martelli: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1682601/4014959

Comment: @PM2Ring Too late, 5 answers already.. :)

Comment: As the answer linked in my previous comment says, it's a Python convention for functions or methods which mutate their arg in-place to return `None`. Almost all the built-ins and standard library modules follow that convention, and so do most 3rd party libraries. Alex mentions there are a couple of exceptions, but even those don't return the mutated object.

Comment: Your code has made me curious. Is there a reason you want your 98 points to have that particular distribution rather than something more random?

Answer (score 3):

First, `random.shuffle` is an in-place operation. Second, you can use `zip` to combine your shuffled lists into points.

```
import random

x = list(range(1, 99))
y = list(range(1, 99))
z = list(range(1, 99))

random.shuffle(x)
random.shuffle(y)
random.shuffle(z)

points = list(zip(x, y, z))
```

If you are using Python 2.X, you can omit all of the `list` casts because `range` and `zip` will already be returning lists.

Comment: A minor comment, I think `list()` over a range is redundant.

Comment: @Rafael Not in python3 :)

Comment: @Rafael It depends on the version of Python

Comment: Correct! I was not sure, I tested it in Python 2, I should had tested in Python 3 as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html).

`random.shuffle` modifies your list in place and returns nothing. Thus, you want

```
>>> a = list(range(1,99))  
print(a)
>>> random.shuffle(a)
print(a)
```

To get a random sample of your 3 lists, use `random.sample`

```
>>> n = 10 # for example
>>> list(zip(random.sample(a, n),random.sample(b, n),random.sample(c, n)))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. `z=random.shuffle(c)` returns NoneType because, it simply modifies an array in-place! If you want a shuffled version, you need only do

`random.shuffle(c)`

`print(c)`

`c` will now be shuffled in place! You can then maybe create a deep copy of c.

This is sort of similar to how the sort function works!

`a = [1, 4, 5, 9, 28, 1]`

`a.sort()`

`a` is sorted in-place, doing something like `b = a.sort()`, would've led to storing `NoneType` in `b`

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, random.shuffle works on the list object and doesn't return anything. To get your code to shuffle and create a list of 3D points can be done easily

```
import random 
x = list(range(1,99))   
y = list(range(1,99))   
z = list(range(1,99))
random.shuffle(x)     
random.shuffle(y)  
random.shuffle(z)    

points = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    points.append((x[i], y[i], z[i]))

print(points)
```

Note this requires x, y and z to be the same length

Answer (score 0):

To answer q1: Shuffle is an in-place operation. Just shuffle(a) etc, to get random lists.
q2. You're looking for the builtin zip(), which will return a list of tuples, stopping at the end of the shortest input iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy you could do something in the lines of:

```
import numpy as np

n = 3
ar = np.array([np.arange(100) for _ in range(3)])
for i in range(n):
    np.random.shuffle(ar[i])

list(map(tuple, np.dstack(ar)[0]))
```