# Python: how to append to a list in the same line the list is declared?

Tags: python, list

Is there any way to replace the following:

```
names = ['john', 'mike', 'james']
names.append('dan')
print(names)
```

with a one-liner similiar to this one (which will print `None`)?:

```
names = ['john', 'mike', 'james'].append('dan')
print(names)
```

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1682567/why-does-list-append-evaluate-to-false-in-a-boolean-context) for why it is bad idea to append and assign it in same line.

Comment: if you know beforehand that `'dan'` will be added to the list, why not initialize it with `'dan'` already in it? I fail to think of a real-life practical scenario for your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`list.append` is an in-place method, so it changes the list *in-place* and always returns `None`.

I don't think you can append *elements* while declaring the list. You can however, extend the new list by adding another list to the new list:

```
names = ['john', 'mike', 'james'] + ['dan']
print(names)
```

Answer (score 6):

How about a adding them?

```
print(['john', 'mike', 'james'] + ['Dan'])
['john', 'mike', 'james', 'Dan']
```

Note that you have to add the second element as a `list` as you can only add elements of the same type, as it occurs with `strings`

Comment: You can append any type of elements in a Python list:

print(['john', 'mike', 'james'] + [1, [1,2]])

is still valid

Comment: You are adding two lists in your example.

Comment: I see know! You were referring to the list and not to the elements of the list.

Comment: Yes @HectorIX  that's right

Answer (score 0):

```
names = ['john', 'mike', 'james']; names.append('dan')
#This is 1 line, note the semi-colon
```

This is slightly cheating, but then again, I fail to see the purpose of putting it on 1 line. Otherwise, just do as what the others have suggested:

```
names = ['john', 'mike', 'james'] + ['dan']
```